# Set button title & action from Mutable Array or Dictionary?

Tags: ios, button, dictionary, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have 4 possible answers: 3 incorrect and 1 correct.

I store the 4 answer in the "choiceValue" mutable array as NSStrings.

```
    [choiceValue addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", incorrectOne]];
[choiceValue addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", incorrectTwo]];
[choiceValue addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", incorrectThree]];
[choiceValue addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", correctAnswer]];
```

I will then shuffle the array order (not part of this question topic)

I want to assign the titles (setTitle) of the 4 buttons based on the (shuffled) array index.

I tried the following code but I believe I'm missing something:

```
    [button1 setTitle:[choiceValue objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(handleIncorrectAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button2 setTitle:[choiceValue objectAtIndex:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(handleCorrectAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button3 setTitle:[choiceValue objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(handleIncorrectAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button4 setTitle:[choiceValue objectAtIndex:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(handleIncorrectAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Ideally, since I call different methods on "action" depending if the answer is correct or incorrect, I believe this would be better done using a dictionary (a pair "title" / "method name").
But for now if I can get it working with the mutable array - it would be great.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend a different approach: Maintain the index of the correct option in a separate variable. Use the same target for all the buttons. Determine in called method which button was pressed (using tags or IBOutletCollection and take action accordingly.

Comment: When you run this, what seems incorrect?

Comment: @SanjayChaudhry first I've tried to use same target but decided to use the advise from this thread as it seems better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368242/ios-passing-a-string-between-two-methods

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy - the problem is the buttons don't display anything. I believe this is because I'm returning a pointer to the NSString not the string itself. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct input is a pointer, no worries there. I was able to get a button to show up with the following code, adapted from your example.

```
NSMutableArray* choiceValue = [NSMutableArray new];
[choiceValue addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 42]];
[button1 setTitle:[choiceValue objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Assumes button1 is already instantiated and visible
```

Are you sure that the strings in your array are being created correctly? You are using %d to specify them, which leads me to believe that they are ints. Can you verify this and log them out with a similar string call? Can you use a hardcoded string as the button title?

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", incorrectOne]); // Test that your string is created correctly
[button1 setTitle:@"42" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Test that your button is capable of displaying a title
```

Comment: This answer my question. Thank you @SomeRandomGuy ! What I did wrong was my array was never initiated as I "initiated" in a different method.

Your top code solved the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you thought my answer directly led to you solving your problem, please mark it as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the checkbox to the left of my answer. It closes out your question and encourages more people to answer your questions in the future!